# Cloud Function http - send back results live as they arrive

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a `Cloud Function` (Python) who does some long(not heavy) calculation that depend on other external APIs so the respond might take some time ( 30 seconds).

```
def test(request):

    request_json = request.get_json()
    for x in y:
      r = get_external_api_respond()
      calculate r and return partial respond
```

The problems and questions are :

1. Is there a way to start returning to the web client results as they arrive to the `Function`? right now I know `http` can only return once to the message and close connection.
2. Pagination in this case will be too complicated to achieve, as results depend on previous results, etc. Are there any solutions in Google Cloud to return live results as they come ? other type of `Function` ?
3. Will it be very expensive if the function stay open for a minute even tough it does not have heavy calculations, just doing multiple API request in loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some intermediary storage, which you will top-up from your function, and read in your HTTP request from web page. I wouldn't call it producer-consumer pattern, really, as you produce once, but consumes as many times as you need to.

You can use a Table Storage or Blob Storage if you use Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/storage/blobs/

With Table, you can just add records as you get them calculated.

With Blob, you can use Append blob type, or just read and write blob again (it seems like you use single producer).

As a bonus, you can distribute your task across multiple functions and get results much faster. This is called scale-out.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, i am doing some reading, but just one  question, how is this fit into a normal http API request? when client make REST request, he makes it to my function, which must return him some json, so where is the database fits in here? maybe the function will return some URL and then client will use it to read db?

Comment: @gotiredofcoding you simply need another HTTP GET function to read from intermediary storage. Use some sort of Correlation ID, GUID for example which you start your worker function. When it produces data into storage, it uses this GUID as a key. Your second function reads data from storage by same GUID. This way you can run multiple functions concurrently.